# Disabling WebGL gl.BLEND doesn't Work

Tags: three.js, webgl

I use `THREE.js` and enable alpha canvas: (because I need to build my WebGL on top of something else)

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas, antialias: false, alpha: true });
```

I set the clear color like this:

```
this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0.0);
```

In each frame:

```
_render () {
    renderer.clear();
    gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
    // ... something else doesn't need to be blended, whose alpha value is not 1.0
}
```

I'm curious why something else still gets blended with the white background even if I disable `gl.BLEND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three.js controls the blending. When you call `renderer.render` it will set the blending calling `gl.enable(gl.BLEND)` for each material depending on whether or not that material needs blending.

On top of that, even with blending off you can draw with a non 1.0 alpha which will end up giving use a canvas that can see through to the background.

Comment: I set all the materials to `transparent=false` and `blending=THREE.NoBlending` but the objects still get blended with the white background. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: That your rendering with a non-0 alpha like it says in the answer. Whether that's your setting or three.js shader issue blending on just means how new pixels get blending with old. With it disabled new pixels get written directly. So if you reader (0,0,0,0) you'll get transparent. And if you render (0.5, 0, 0, .5) you'll get 50% transparent red, etc..

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You cleared to (0xFFFFFF,0) which is a transparent background so of course you're going to see through the canvas anywhere you didn't render. Anywhere you did render you need to make sure you render with a solid color. Blending has nothing to do with it. Blending only affects the pixels rendered by WebGL into the canvas with other pixels in the canvas. Blending the canvas with its background happens in the browser like any other HTML element. BTW: 0xFFFFFF,0 is [an invalid color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643558/128511)